# Using a Windows Forms Application out of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am just wondering if there is a somewhat simple way to use a Windows Forms Application program outside of Visual Studios. If so could someone elaborate on it?

Comment: Yes.  You can build an installer for your application and run it outside of Visual Studio that way.

Comment: Wouldnt you just go to the solutions bin directory and double click the executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have compiled the files simply navigate to the

> Debug/Release folder

and run the executable. Any dependencies can be configured to be output to that folder in

> Project properties (Build Tab, Output path)

You can also set references to Copy local in the **Property Window** within Visual Studio, which ensures references are copied to Debug/Release folder depending on which configuration you have Visual studio in.

Or build an installer as Brian describes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that as soon as I finish the project haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The steps to do this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

In a nutshell:

1. Add a new install project to your solution.
2. Add targets from all of the projects you want to be installed.
3. Configure pre-requisites and choose the location from where missing components must be installed (if applicable).
4. Configure your installer settings - company name, version...
5. Build the project and you are good-to-go.
6. Run the installer (setup.exe) or right-click the setup project in the solution explorer and select "Install", then run it from the install folder like any other app. (thank you, retailcoder)

It can be as simple or complex as you would like it to be.

Comment: 6. Run the installer (setup.exe) or right-click the setup project in the solution explorer and select "Install", then run it from the install folder like any other app.